# How to fix my PL/SQL function that give user input it will go through the conditional statements and output the correct line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been trying to create a function that accepts user input of various dates then if the dates fall into a conditional category it should output the correct statement.

I've tried using the compiler to figure out what is wrong, but I think I may be using the wrong datatype or variable. I believe I also properly closed out all of my statements.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION season (x in date) return date
IS
    Begin
    if (x BETWEEN '01-Dec-18' AND '28-May-19') then
        dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Winter');

    else if (x BETWEEN '01-MAR-18' AND '31-May-19') then
       dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Summer');

    else if (x BETWEEN '01-Jun-18' AND '31-Aug-19') then
    dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Fall');

else if (x BETWEEN '01-Sep-18' AND '30-Nov-19') then
    dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Fall'); 
END if;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SELECT season('29-JAN-19') FROM DUAL;
SELECT season('11-APR-19') FROM DUAL;
```

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if

Comment: fyi `if` conditions have no brackets in PL/SQL. Also you might consider coming to a decision about capitalisation :)

Answer (score 1):

PLSQL uses ELSIF, not ELSE IF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION season (x in date) return date
IS
Begin
  IF (x BETWEEN '01-Dec-18' AND '28-May-19') then
        dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Winter');

  ELSIF (x BETWEEN '01-MAR-18' AND '31-May-19') then
       dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Summer');

  ELSIF (x BETWEEN '01-Jun-18' AND '31-Aug-19') then
    dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Fall');

  ELSIF (x BETWEEN '01-Sep-18' AND '30-Nov-19') then
    dbms_output.put_line (x||' is Fall'); 
  END IF;
END;
```

As an aside, this is quite contextual; the seasons experienced in the different hemispheres are different

Consider just using the month, not the year, otherwise you'll have to update your code every year:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Season(p_iDate in date)
return VARCHAR2
IS
  nMonth  PLS_INTEGER;
  vSeason VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  nMonth:=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p_iDate);
  vSeason:=CASE
             WHEN nMonth IN (12,1,2)  THEN 'winter'
             WHEN nMonth IN (3,4,5)   THEN 'spring'
             WHEN nMonth IN (6,7,8)   THEN 'summer'
             WHEN nMonth IN (9,10,11) THEN 'fall'
           END;
  RETURN vSeason;
END season;
```

Something like that anyway.

Test this in Oracle 11g Express Edition.

```
select season(sysdate) as season_name
from dual;

SEASON_NAME
summer
```

Comment: That did it...Wow I guess I stared at it a bit too long and never noticed... Thank you!